# Display whole number ASP.net using ToString() format

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-formatting, tostring

I am having issue with the ToString(). I want to display my whole number from this :

```
150000
```

To this :

```
150 000
```

Here is what I tried :

```
string myNumber = Convert.ToInt64(input_value.Text).ToString("D");
```

The `string myNumber` is a variable I will associate to a label to display the value (`input_value`) user entered. This value is a `<asp:TextBox>`. Finally, I want to add some space each 3 digits to make the value clearer.

Is there any other solution to do the same in ASP.net ? Because this one seems not to work.

*Note : I also tried with `[...].ToString("N1");` and it works perfectly, but I don't want the last `.0` in the displayed result `150 000.0`, which is not the proper whole number format.*

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom `NumberFormatInfo` with `" "` as thousand separator:

```
var formatInfoWithSpaceGroupSep = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
formatInfoWithSpaceGroupSep.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
formatInfoWithSpaceGroupSep.NumberDecimalDigits = 0; // or "N0" instead of "N" below
Console.Write(num.ToString("N", formatInfoWithSpaceGroupSep)); //123 234 000
```

You have to use [`N` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#NFormatString) which supports group separators instead of [`D`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#DFormatString).

Comment: Thank you @Tim Shmelter, it works perfectly and is more reliable than my own solution :).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for poluate. I found my issue. Let me explain :

I didn't got that in the `N1` formating, the `1` mean "*1 digit after the comma*". So I just have to set the format string to `n0`.

Comment: But this will give you the result with `,` is that what you intended ?

Comment: It depends on current culture

Comment: The most fantastic with this formatting, is that it get the current location you run the program (for example, I am located in Paris). So if you come from eu, your number will automatically fit the EU generic whole number format, which display some spaces between 3 digits. And you probably runing my snippet from an American country, so it gives you some comas !

Answer (score 0):

You can use # symbol to specify number of digits in your result set with space delim:

```
 string num = Convert.ToInt64(input_value.Text).
                      ToString("# ### ### ### ### ### ###").
                      Trim();
 //Output 150 000 and covers any Int64 digit in input_value.Text
```

Comment: Like Ofiris said, the limit of this solution is that if you don't know the user input number length, you can't prevent the solution to be sur at 100% if number is too large. But thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @ofiris We can use ### ### ### for this. If we expect max as Int64, than ToString("# ### ### ### ### ### ###") would cover all Int64 cases

Comment: @Zeratops see my comment on Ofiris question

Comment: The input is dynamic, the string format is constant in your answer.

Comment: @Ofiris Does it makes sence? He can put Convert.ToInt64(input_value.Text).ToString("# ### ### ### ### ### ###");

Comment: No, `Convert.ToInt64(250).ToString("# ### ### ### ### ### ###").Count(); //9`

Comment: @Ofiris Yep, we could use Trim() to clear the result